# UIView as colors legend?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, colors, legend

Is there a way to get a UIView color as a legend?

Two examples of this:

[image: Legend1]

[image: legend2]

Comment: For second case you can apply a gradient.

Answer (score 1):

well the easiest would be to set the background of your UIView as that image...

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
```

Comment: To clarify: yes it is possible to draw it in code, but the pre-rendered image (PTBG's suggestion) is by far the best option.

Comment: Is there a way that does not use the background image?

Comment: I don't think its the best option. For legends the colors matter. One time you want it from blue to red, another time you want it monochrome from black to green... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to draw it. Make a subclass of `UIView`, implement `drawRect` method:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)dummy
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NR_SEGMENTS; i++)
    {
        [[self colorForIndex:i] setFill];
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0,
                              CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / NR_SEGMENTS,
                              CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds)));
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                              CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / NR_SEGMENTS,
                              0);
    }
}
```

`colorForIndex:` should return some color.